# file_get_contents(): stream does not support seeking

Tags: php

I'm getting this error:

```
`file_get_contents(): stream does not support seeking
```

I have no clue to fix it. There is no Resource Id or whatsoever.

This is my code:

```
$postData = array('name' => $name, 'description' => $description, 'date_begin' => $start, 'date_end' => $end);

  $stream = array(
            'http' => array(
                'header'  =>   "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n"
                                . "Authorization: Basic Y3Nub2VrOnNuMDNr\r\n",
                'method'  => 'POST',
                'content' => http_build_query($postData)
            )
        );

    return stream_context_create($stream);
```

And in the file where the stream returns to. Its the function `getApiContext`.

```
$responseJson = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://10.0.0.89/api/v1/projects', false, BaseController::getApiContext(), true));
```

And then I get this annoying error. I know about cUrl, but I must use streams.

Comment: Are you getting this on a particular line of code? What line does that correspond to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why have you got `true` on your `file_get_contents`  offset param?  perhaps you meant to put this in the `json_decode`  if so, try this:

`$responseJson = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://10.0.0.89/api/v1/projects', false, BaseController::getApiContext()),true);`

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are passing the fourth parameter to file_get_contents, this is not supported for remote streams (as per the documentation: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)

Change your call to file_get_contents to exclude it (or pass it to json_decode if that was your intent).

```
$responseJson = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://10.0.0.89/api/v1/projects', false, BaseController::getApiContext()));
```